# Curve from a Douglas-Peucker line

Tags: algorithm, polyline-creation

When generating a line using the Douglas-Peucker Algorithm the resulting object is a line with steep angles, I would like to "smooth" that line and making it look less "squarish" using curves, like bezier curves: there is an algorithm for that ?

Answer (score 2):

take a look at: http://ricegisinfo.blogspot.co.at/2009/12/tuesday-tools-mapshaper.html

the  visvalingam-algorith is described here:

http://www2.dcs.hull.ac.uk/CISRG/publications/DPs/DP10/DP10.html

mapshaper (http://mapshaper.com/test/MapShaper.swf) an online flash-tool,  uses a special version of  visvalingam, which should do what you want, but you will need to contact the author for more infos about this special version of visvalingam . the author is matthew bloch (http://maps.grammata.com/)